# как убрать непонятные отступы у фоновой картинки?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! У картинки появляются отступы с увеличением высоты, хотя высота ее в реальности выше заданной. Если убрать высоту, то она вообще не показывается. Что это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
}

header {
  width: 1921px;
  height: 1280px;
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/28866/3dec723b-5830-4fb2-ad06-a163ed710303/s1200") no-repeat center center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* background-zize: cover; */
  /* background-size: cover; */
  /* background-color: pink; */
  display: inline-block;
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */
  /* background-attachment: local; */
}

.wrapper {
  /* width: 700px; */
  /* height: 800px; */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>jjjjjj</header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Выложите пример кода чтобы его смогли поправить

Comment: У вас же `background-size: cover` стоит. Размер масштабируется с сохранением пропорций + ширина 820px. Можете поставить `background-zize: contain`, если это то что вам нужно.

Comment: ставила - при задаче реального размера изображения выходит то же самое

Comment: Приведите Ваш код, чтобы можно было понять причину проблемы! Можно проверить `background-size: 100% 100%;` должно заполнить весь блок, если все же остаются отступы - проблема с самим блоком.

Comment: padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: inline-block;
}

header {
    width: 1921px;
    height: 1280px;
    background: url("../../images/aaa.jpg") no-repeat  center bottom;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-zize: contain;
    /* background-size: cover; */
    /* background-color: pink; */
    display: inline-block;
    /* background-attachment: fixed; */
    background-attachment: local;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
}

Comment: я пытаюсь разобраться как тут добавить код нормально

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css//style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>MoGo</title>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>

Comment: background-size: 100% 100% - пишет ошибку

Comment: Пожалуйста, не выкладывайте код в комментариях: под вопросом есть "править", нажмите и отредактируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: Добавил реальную картинку в код. Никаких отступов не наблюдается. Ни с `cover` ни с `100% 100%`

Comment: у меня с другими картинками тоже не наблюдается такого. А нужная 1921 на 1280 px размером написанно, но почему-то так косячит

Comment: ну да, логично, она просто так сделана и мною неправильно обрезана) спасибо всем за ответы!